Why the assignment generated by Kafka Streams TaskAssignor needs a followup probing rebalance?
My application is using Kakfa streams 3.4.1 for streaming processing, and the topology is simply one input topic and 2 stateful processing nodes and a sink.
the following are the basic configurations

number of application instances: 12
number of threads per application instance: 4
number of partitions of the input topic:30
num.standby.replicas=0(default)
max.warmup.replicas=2(default)

While investigating the issue of some unexpected rebalances, I noticed the following log( formatted for viewing easily) from HighAvailabilityTaskAssignor.
I tried to read the code to understand the logic of the code, but I still can't understand why the assignment result requires a probing rebalance(probingRebalanceNeeded=true). It seems to me that neither active nor standby tasks need to be moved, kindly shed some light on  what I missed.
Decided on assignment: 
{
  97405f8e-c74c-494e-886b-3eb8063c0fdf=
    [
      activeTasks: ([0_0, 0_2, 0_14])
      standbyTasks: ([])
      prevActiveTasks: ([0_0, 0_2, 0_14])
      prevStandbyTasks: ([])
      changelogOffsetTotalsByTask: ([0_0=-2, 0_2=-2, 0_14=-2])
      taskLagTotals: ([0_0=-2, 0_1=2019630220, 0_2=-2, 0_3=2024870678, 0_4=2028179500,
        0_5=2017468850, 0_6=2018701470, 0_7=2017341808, 0_8=2020834068, 0_9=2020712115,
        0_10=2029211665, 0_11=2026533055, 0_12=2031519148, 0_13=2022231538, 0_14=-2,
        0_15=2026682653, 0_16=2018526533, 0_17=2020990444, 0_18=2012430598, 0_19=2018594340,
        0_20=2027859564, 0_21=2026399108, 0_22=2027341433, 0_23=2016975135, 0_24=2024962902,
        0_25=2018789694, 0_26=2029583989, 0_27=2026366783, 0_28=2023064868, 0_29=2023926478])
      clientTags: ([])
      capacity: 4
      assigned: 3
    ],

  b9e806f4-930a-4a12-8396-cec93d0a003e=
    [
      activeTasks: ([0_15, 0_27])
      standbyTasks: ([0_1])
      prevActiveTasks: ([0_15, 0_27])
      prevStandbyTasks: ([0_1])
      changelogOffsetTotalsByTask: ([0_1=2001229294, 0_15=-2, 0_27=-2])
      taskLagTotals: ([0_0=2020326550, 0_1=18400926, 0_2=2019506715, 0_3=2024870678, 0_4=2028179500,
        0_5=2017468850, 0_6=2018701470, 0_7=2017341808, 0_8=2020834068, 0_9=2020712115,
        0_10=2029211665, 0_11=2026533055, 0_12=2031519148, 0_13=2022231538, 0_14=2022325839,
        0_15=-2, 0_16=2018526533, 0_17=2020990444, 0_18=2012430598, 0_19=2018594340,
        0_20=2027859564, 0_21=2026399108, 0_22=2027341433, 0_23=2016975135, 0_24=2024962902,
        0_25=2018789694, 0_26=2029583989, 0_27=-2, 0_28=2023064868, 0_29=2023926478])
      clientTags: ([])
      capacity: 4
      assigned: 3
    ],

  08890537-ee25-42b4-aa3e-01060723a2a6=
    [
      activeTasks: ([0_3, 0_4, 0_16, 0_29])
      standbyTasks: ([0_2])
      prevActiveTasks: ([0_3, 0_4, 0_16, 0_29])
      prevStandbyTasks: ([0_2])
      changelogOffsetTotalsByTask: ([0_2=2001225092, 0_3=-2, 0_4=-2, 0_16=-2, 0_29=-2])
      taskLagTotals: ([0_0=2020326550, 0_1=2019630220, 0_2=18281623, 0_3=-2, 0_4=-2,
        0_5=2017468850, 0_6=2018701470, 0_7=2017341808, 0_8=2020834068, 0_9=2020712115,
        0_10=2029211665, 0_11=2026533055, 0_12=2031519148, 0_13=2022231538, 0_14=2022325839,
        0_15=2026682653, 0_16=-2, 0_17=2020990444, 0_18=2012430598, 0_19=2018594340,
        0_20=2027859564, 0_21=2026399108, 0_22=2027341433, 0_23=2016975135, 0_24=2024962902,
        0_25=2018789694, 0_26=2029583989, 0_27=2026366783, 0_28=2023064868, 0_29=-2])
      clientTags: ([])
      capacity: 4
      assigned: 5],

  124575d3-049b-4bab-b134-68d26fad5a6f=
    [
      activeTasks: ([0_17, 0_19, 0_21])
      standbyTasks: ([])
      prevActiveTasks: ([0_17, 0_19, 0_21])
      prevStandbyTasks: ([])
      changelogOffsetTotalsByTask: ([0_17=-2, 0_19=-2, 0_21=-2])
      taskLagTotals: ([0_0=2020326550, 0_1=2019630220, 0_2=2019506715, 0_3=2024870678, 0_4=2028179500,
        0_5=2017468850, 0_6=2018701470, 0_7=2017341808, 0_8=2020834068, 0_9=2020712115,
        0_10=2029211665, 0_11=2026533055, 0_12=2031519148, 0_13=2022231538, 0_14=2022325839,
        0_15=2026682653, 0_16=2018526533, 0_17=-2, 0_18=2012430598, 0_19=-2,
        0_20=2027859564, 0_21=-2, 0_22=2027341433, 0_23=2016975135, 0_24=2024962902,
        0_25=2018789694, 0_26=2029583989, 0_27=2026366783, 0_28=2023064868, 0_29=2023926478])
      clientTags: ([])
      capacity: 4
      assigned: 3],

  1dfe27d3-6a5d-4956-b4db-997c588882cd=
    [
      activeTasks: ([0_1, 0_18, 0_20])
      standbyTasks: ([])
      prevActiveTasks: ([0_1, 0_18, 0_20])
      prevStandbyTasks: ([])
      changelogOffsetTotalsByTask: ([0_1=-2, 0_18=-2, 0_20=-2])
      taskLagTotals: ([0_0=2020326550, 0_1=-2, 0_2=2019506715, 0_3=2024870678, 0_4=2028179500,
        0_5=2017468850, 0_6=2018701470, 0_7=2017341808, 0_8=2020834068, 0_9=2020712115,
        0_10=2029211665, 0_11=2026533055, 0_12=2031519148, 0_13=2022231538, 0_14=2022325839,
        0_15=2026682653, 0_16=2018526533, 0_17=2020990444, 0_18=-2, 0_19=2018594340,
        0_20=-2, 0_21=2026399108, 0_22=2027341433, 0_23=2016975135, 0_24=2024962902,
        0_25=2018789694, 0_26=2029583989, 0_27=2026366783, 0_28=2023064868, 0_29=2023926478])
      clientTags: ([])
      capacity: 4
      assigned: 3
    ],
  34489b10-15af-42f8-a8cf-22a64fc80c7d=
    [
      activeTasks: ([0_5, 0_6])
      standbyTasks: ([])
      prevActiveTasks: ([0_5, 0_6])
      prevStandbyTasks: ([])
      changelogOffsetTotalsByTask: ([0_5=-2, 0_6=-2])
      taskLagTotals: ([0_0=2020326550, 0_1=2019630220, 0_2=2019506715, 0_3=2024870678, 0_4=2028179500,
        0_5=-2, 0_6=-2, 0_7=2017341808, 0_8=2020834068, 0_9=2020712115,
        0_10=2029211665, 0_11=2026533055, 0_12=2031519148, 0_13=2022231538, 0_14=2022325839,
        0_15=2026682653, 0_16=2018526533, 0_17=2020990444, 0_18=2012430598, 0_19=2018594340,
        0_20=2027859564, 0_21=2026399108, 0_22=2027341433, 0_23=2016975135, 0_24=2024962902,
        0_25=2018789694, 0_26=2029583989, 0_27=2026366783, 0_28=2023064868, 0_29=2023926478])
      clientTags: ([])
      capacity: 4
      assigned: 2
    ],
  41abcc49-54c9-4afb-9a19-b2952f522abd=
    [
      activeTasks: ([0_8, 0_22])
      standbyTasks: ([])
      prevActiveTasks: ([0_8, 0_22])
      prevStandbyTasks: ([])
      changelogOffsetTotalsByTask: ([0_8=-2, 0_22=-2])
      taskLagTotals: ([0_0=2020326550, 0_1=2019630220, 0_2=2019506715, 0_3=2024870678, 0_4=2028179500,
        0_5=2017468850, 0_6=2018701470, 0_7=2017341808, 0_8=-2, 0_9=2020712115,
        0_10=2029211665, 0_11=2026533055, 0_12=2031519148, 0_13=2022231538, 0_14=2022325839,
        0_15=2026682653, 0_16=2018526533, 0_17=2020990444, 0_18=2012430598, 0_19=2018594340,
        0_20=2027859564, 0_21=2026399108, 0_22=-2, 0_23=2016975135, 0_24=2024962902,
        0_25=2018789694, 0_26=2029583989, 0_27=2026366783, 0_28=2023064868, 0_29=2023926478])
      clientTags: ([])
      capacity: 4
      assigned: 2
    ],
  4598e980-b8e9-485f-b8ee-7293e1da26b3=
    [
      activeTasks: ([0_9, 0_23])
      standbyTasks: ([])
      prevActiveTasks: ([0_9, 0_23])
      prevStandbyTasks: ([])
      changelogOffsetTotalsByTask: ([0_9=-2, 0_23=-2])
      taskLagTotals: ([0_0=2020326550, 0_1=2019630220, 0_2=2019506715, 0_3=2024870678, 0_4=2028179500,
        0_5=2017468850, 0_6=2018701470, 0_7=2017341808, 0_8=2020834068, 0_9=-2,
        0_10=2029211665, 0_11=2026533055, 0_12=2031519148, 0_13=2022231538, 0_14=2022325839,
        0_15=2026682653, 0_16=2018526533, 0_17=2020990444, 0_18=2012430598, 0_19=2018594340,
        0_20=2027859564, 0_21=2026399108, 0_22=2027341433, 0_23=-2,
        0_24=2024962902, 0_25=2018789694, 0_26=2029583989, 0_27=2026366783, 0_28=2023064868, 0_29=2023926478])
      clientTags: ([])
      capacity: 4
      assigned: 2
    ],
  486f129a-ad5c-42a8-a137-ba13559a476c=
    [
      activeTasks: ([0_10, 0_12, 0_24])
      standbyTasks: ([])
      prevActiveTasks: ([0_10, 0_12, 0_24])
      prevStandbyTasks: ([])
      changelogOffsetTotalsByTask: ([0_10=-2, 0_12=-2, 0_24=-2])
      taskLagTotals: ([0_0=2020326550, 0_1=2019630220, 0_2=2019506715, 0_3=2024870678, 0_4=2028179500,
        0_5=2017468850, 0_6=2018701470, 0_7=2017341808, 0_8=2020834068, 0_9=2020712115,
        0_10=-2, 0_11=2026533055, 0_12=-2, 0_13=2022231538, 0_14=2022325839, 0_15=2026682653,
        0_16=2018526533, 0_17=2020990444, 0_18=2012430598, 0_19=2018594340, 0_20=2027859564,
        0_21=2026399108, 0_22=2027341433, 0_23=2016975135, 0_24=-2,
        0_25=2018789694, 0_26=2029583989, 0_27=2026366783, 0_28=2023064868, 0_29=2023926478])
      clientTags: ([])
      capacity: 4
      assigned: 3
    ],
  5774fb10-4da7-470d-969a-b17848b4d1f2=
    [
      activeTasks: ([0_11, 0_13, 0_28])
      standbyTasks: ([])
      prevActiveTasks: ([0_11, 0_13, 0_28])
      prevStandbyTasks: ([])
      changelogOffsetTotalsByTask: ([0_11=-2, 0_13=-2, 0_28=-2])
      taskLagTotals: ([0_0=2020326550, 0_1=2019630220, 0_2=2019506715, 0_3=2024870678, 0_4=2028179500,
        0_5=2017468850, 0_6=2018701470, 0_7=2017341808, 0_8=2020834068, 0_9=2020712115,
        0_10=2029211665, 0_11=-2, 0_12=2031519148, 0_13=-2, 0_14=2022325839,
        0_15=2026682653, 0_16=2018526533, 0_17=2020990444, 0_18=2012430598, 0_19=2018594340,
        0_20=2027859564, 0_21=2026399108, 0_22=2027341433, 0_23=2016975135, 0_24=2024962902,
        0_25=2018789694, 0_26=2029583989, 0_27=2026366783, 0_28=-2, 0_29=2023926478])
      clientTags: ([])
      capacity: 4
      assigned: 3
    ],
  6fac0f01-44a5-41e7-b393-2846fa9cad75=
    [
      activeTasks: ([0_26])
      standbyTasks: ([])
      prevActiveTasks: ([0_26])
      prevStandbyTasks: ([])
      changelogOffsetTotalsByTask: ([0_26=-2])
      taskLagTotals: ([0_0=2020326550, 0_1=2019630220, 0_2=2019506715, 0_3=2024870678, 0_4=2028179500,
        0_5=2017468850, 0_6=2018701470, 0_7=2017341808, 0_8=2020834068, 0_9=2020712115,
        0_10=2029211665, 0_11=2026533055, 0_12=2031519148, 0_13=2022231538, 0_14=2022325839,
        0_15=2026682653, 0_16=2018526533, 0_17=2020990444, 0_18=2012430598, 0_19=2018594340,
        0_20=2027859564, 0_21=2026399108, 0_22=2027341433, 0_23=2016975135, 0_24=2024962902,
        0_25=2018789694, 0_26=-2, 0_27=2026366783, 0_28=2023064868, 0_29=2023926478])
      clientTags: ([])
      capacity: 4
      assigned: 1
    ],

  701050ba-a2da-479c-a3a8-e1d9e9392453=
    [
      activeTasks: ([0_7, 0_25])
      standbyTasks: ([])
      prevActiveTasks: ([0_7, 0_25])
      prevStandbyTasks: ([])
      changelogOffsetTotalsByTask: ([0_7=-2, 0_25=-2])
      taskLagTotals: ([0_0=2020326550, 0_1=2019630220, 0_2=2019506715, 0_3=2024870678, 0_4=2028179500,
        0_5=2017468850, 0_6=2018701470, 0_7=-2, 0_8=2020834068, 0_9=2020712115,
        0_10=2029211665, 0_11=2026533055, 0_12=2031519148, 0_13=2022231538, 0_14=2022325839,
        0_15=2026682653, 0_16=2018526533, 0_17=2020990444, 0_18=2012430598, 0_19=2018594340,
        0_20=2027859564, 0_21=2026399108, 0_22=2027341433, 0_23=2016975135, 0_24=2024962902,
        0_25=-2, 0_26=2029583989, 0_27=2026366783, 0_28=2023064868, 0_29=2023926478])
      clientTags: ([])
      capacity: 4
      assigned: 2
    ]
 }

 with followup probing rebalance.



